# Phpmyadmin not found, when running laravel application

Tags: server, php, nginx, phpmyadmin

I installed phpmyadmin on my vps `Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS` with `nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)`.

I created a symbolic link:

`sudo ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin /var/www/html/phpmyadmin`

Furthermore, I tried to secure my access:

```
sudo mv phpmyadmin db-admin
ls -l
```

I am currently running my laravel application on my server.

My application file in my `sites-enabled` directory looks like the following:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name http://example.com/;
    root /var/www/laravel_application/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;
  
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

}
```

When trying to access phpadmin under `example.com/db-admin`, I get:

[image]

Any suggestions why I cannot run phpmyadmin and laravel in parallel?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: Do you know where that 4_4 message is coming from? That's not a standard Apache page, which likely means something is overriding your settings. You may also find it much easier to work with a downloaded version of phpMyAdmin (if you really must use that software) that is written to the `/db-admin` directory. There are fewer edge cases to work around.

Comment: How about [*not* installing phpMyAdmin](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/security/stop-installing-phpmyadmin) for security reasons? Any modern MySQL GUI client program will be more secure and support a lot more features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache will not follow symbolic links by default you need to enable them.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thx for your reply! I am using `nginx` instead of apache. Can you adapt your answer?

Comment: I have no clue what to for nginx, I would expect their procedure for following symbolic links to be similar. BTW this security through obscurity you try with the renaming is useless. The bots that scan the net 24/7/365 are supposed to be so stupid to miss this trick that is all over the place, like changing the default port too. I do not think so, they go and go many times a day they scan everything in existence. Set it up properly and securely and be done with this waste of time. If it is so insecure it cannot be secured it should never be on the machine.